# Close current notification before next one displays?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I fire notications which close automatically with a timeout.

But, some notifications will fire before the timeout finishes.

So, how can I close the current notification before next one displays?

I only ever want one displaying at any particular time.

BACKGROUND:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    var notify = webkitNotifications.createNotification('icon-48.png', 'Notification', request.message);

    notify.show();
    setTimeout(function(){ notify.cancel(); },10000);
});
```

CONTEXT:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({

  message: "Fetching stuff from " + thestuffname},  
  function(response) {
  return response;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make notify var global, and cancel it before creating a new one

like this:

```
var notify;

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(notify){
        notify.cancel();
    }
    notify = webkitNotifications.createNotification('icon-48.png', 'Notification', request.message);

    notify.show();
    setTimeout(function(){ notify.cancel(); },10000);
});
```

Comment: @kdrureidy Thanks! Works as advertised. Next, will be how to cancel a notification when an Ajax call completes successfully.